# Weird Characters Displayed on Build, but not on Debug

Tags: java, string, url, web

I'm developing a Java Application using Netbeans, but while I run my app in Debug, or plain running it from Netbeans, my screen looks like so:
[image: Good]. Yet, when I try to run from the Built jar in the `dist` folder, it looks like so: [image: Bad].

Here is the method in which I am using to receive the content. The method is intended to get the source of text file from the web.

```
public static ArrayList<String> getUrlSource(String urlF) throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL(urlF);
    Scanner s = new Scanner(url.openStream());
    ArrayList<String> fileLines = new ArrayList<>();
    while (s.hasNextLine())
    {
        fileLines.add(s.nextLine());
    }
    return fileLines;
}
```

Comment: I would guess that the streams/URL are actually different, hence different results.  What URL are you having the problem with?

Comment: @markspace http://godispower.us/Application/Updates.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default charset may be different depending on how you launch the application. Try specifying the charset explicitly :

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(url.openStream(), "UTF-8");
```

Comment: This is exactly what I just figured out how to do, but thanks anyhow! I will accept your answer and upvote the other one as well.

Comment: Yes I saw that - You have to type fast on SO :)

Answer (score 2):

You're looking at the UTF-8 [Byte Order Marker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8)

> The UTF-8 representation of the BOM is the byte sequence 0xEF,0xBB,0xBF. A text editor or web browser misinterpreting the text as ISO-8859-1 or CP1252 will display the characters ï»¿ for this.

Comment: Is there perhaps a way where I can force it to parse it as UTF-8?

Comment: You've posted where you added the lines to your array, but you haven't posted how you *print* them.  I am assuming your console is not UTF-8 friendly, or is but is not BOM friendly.  Do you see the BOM prefix in your *fileLines* array when you look in a debugger?

Comment: Scanner s = new Scanner(is, "UTF-8"); IT WORKS :)